# Image resizing : original color has been changed after the resize

Tags: java, image-processing, playframework

I'm using Play!Framework 1.x, one of its useful tool is the class `Images`, which allow me to resize an Image on the fly.

Here's the code from `Images.resize` :

```
/**
 * Resize an image
 * @param originalImage The image file
 * @param to The destination file
 * @param w The new width (or -1 to proportionally resize) or the maxWidth if keepRatio is true
 * @param h The new height (or -1 to proportionally resize) or the maxHeight if keepRatio is true
 * @param keepRatio : if true, resize will keep the original image ratio and use w and h as max dimensions
 */
public static void resize(File originalImage, File to, int w, int h, boolean keepRatio) {
try {
    BufferedImage source = ImageIO.read(originalImage);
    int owidth = source.getWidth();
    int oheight = source.getHeight();
    double ratio = (double) owidth / oheight;

    int maxWidth = w;
    int maxHeight = h;

    if (w < 0 && h < 0) {
        w = owidth;
        h = oheight;
    }
    if (w < 0 && h > 0) {
        w = (int) (h * ratio);
    }
    if (w > 0 && h < 0) {
        h = (int) (w / ratio);
    }

    if(keepRatio) {
        h = (int) (w / ratio);
        if(h > maxHeight) {
            h = maxHeight;
            w = (int) (h * ratio);
        }
        if(w > maxWidth) {
            w = maxWidth;
            h = (int) (w / ratio);
        }
    }

    String mimeType = "image/jpeg";
    if (to.getName().endsWith(".png")) {
        mimeType = "image/png";
    }
    if (to.getName().endsWith(".gif")) {
        mimeType = "image/gif";
    }

    // out
    BufferedImage dest = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Image srcSized = source.getScaledInstance(w, h, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    Graphics graphics = dest.getGraphics();
    graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    graphics.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
    graphics.drawImage(srcSized, 0, 0, null);
    ImageWriter writer = ImageIO.getImageWritersByMIMEType(mimeType).next();
    ImageWriteParam params = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
    FileImageOutputStream toFs = new FileImageOutputStream(to);
    writer.setOutput(toFs);
    IIOImage image = new IIOImage(dest, null, null);
    writer.write(null, image, params);
    toFs.flush();
    toFs.close();
    writer.dispose();
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}

}
```

Here's how I use it :

```
File old = new File("1.jpg");
File n = new File("output.jpg");
Images.resize(old, n, 800, 800, true);
```

The original image `1.jpg`:
[image]

And the `output.jpg`:
[image]

Can anyone explain what's going on here ? Thanks !

Comment: It's a (known) bug in the `JPEGImageWriter` I think. The image is stored in YCbCr color space, but is incorrectly interpreted as RGB. As you are not passing any meta data to the `IIOImage` and passing only defaults for the `ImageWriteParam`, you could try using `writer.write(dest)` instead, and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: @haraldK, `writer.write(dest)` doesn't make any difference. Is there any parameter I could use in `ImageWriteParam` ?

Comment: No, I'm afraid not. But what could possibly work, is to get the metadata from the original image, and pass that metadata to the `IIOImage`. If there's an EXIF segment, that may make a difference.

Comment: @haraldK - it does solve the color issue. For this particular image it means that the file-size will NOT decrease though.. apparently the meta-data of this particular image is huge...

Comment: You could look into the metadata and delete items that are large, and not needed. I suspect that the EXIF and maybe ICC color profile is taking up the most part. And you probably only need parts of the EXIF data. Sorry for being vague, but this is a large topic...

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this, too and believe it's an JRE bug. I worked around it by not using [`getScaledInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#getScaledInstance%28int,%20int,%20int%29) and instead [scaling while drawing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage%28java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.Color,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver%29).

Answer (score 0):

Ah. I was too slow to answer. But yes, it is most likely a bug. Came across this problem myself. You have to work around it. Try scaling the image as Waldheinz said. That was what I did too.

This is the link I used to do my scaling :http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0243.html, so you have more references in adition to waldheinz's